# unexpected 'array' text appear in my site's feed

Tags: image, rss, feed

I have been playing around with my site's function.php to show images in my feeds. The image appear nicely but there is this 'array' text appear after the image. Honestly, this is out of my league for I am just a rookie in this php codes. Hope somebody here have answer for this.

my function.php code is:

```
function featuredtoRSS($content) {
    global $post;
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('image_1'));
    ?>
    <img class="entry-thumb wp-post-image" width="80px" style="float:left" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php get_the_title(get_field('image_1')) ?>" />
    <?php { $content = '' . $image . '' . $content; }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredtoRSS');
```

I use wordpress 3.3.1
this is my feed look like (see 'array' text between image and the content)
http://autonewsmedia.com/feed

Comment: sorry about the code, need to learn how to do it properly

Comment: No need to be sorry, but could you format the code properly (multiple lines) so that people will actually be able to read it (and help you). Thanks

Comment: hi m90, that's what i mean about formatting the code preperly :)

Answer (score 0):

got it, change the code to:

```
function featuredtoRSS($content) {
global $post;
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('image_1')); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php get_the_title(get_field('image_1')) ?>" />
<?php return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredtoRSS');
```

hope it will helpfull for others.